# Using C# how can I convert from the Classic ASP Intrinsic Request.QueryString to a NameValueCollection?

Tags: c#, asp-classic

I am trying to use the Classic ASP Intrinsic objects in C#. Through using the ASPTypeLibrary.

I would like to convert the Classic ASP Request object `Request.QueryString` and `Request.Form` into NameValueCollections.

How can I do this?

Comment: The `QueryString` and `Form` collections in Classic ASP are `Scripting.Dictionary` objects (key-value pair), can you not just iterate through them and populate a `NameValueCollection`?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to convert the Request.QueryString and Request.Form objects into NameValueCollections. How can I do this?

The return type of them both is `NameValueCollection`:

- `public NameValueCollection QueryString { get; }`
- `public NameValueCollection Form { get; }`

You can simply foreach them, for example:

```
   PrintKeysAndValues(Request.Form);
   PrintKeysAndValues(Request.Request);


   public static void PrintKeysAndValues( NameValueCollection myCol )  {
      Console.WriteLine( "   KEY        VALUE" );
      foreach ( String s in myCol.AllKeys )
         Console.WriteLine( "   {0,-10} {1}", s, myCol[s] );
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
```

**So you don't need to convert them.**

Comment: Someone edited my question to remove the asp-classic tag, the ASPTypeLibrary version of Request does not return NameValueCollections

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "convert"? Both those properties **are** `NameValueCollections`:

- [`HttpRequest.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a `NameValueCollection` of form variables. If the page was posted using the HTTP verb `POST`, the data comes from the request body; if the page was posted using the HTTP verb `GET`, the data comes from the query string.
- [`HttpRequest.QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a `NameValueCollection` of key/value pairs taken from the...wait for it...query string of the form `...?key1=value1&key1=value1&...`. Any repeated keys will result in the values being concatated into a single string with each individual value separated by commas: `...?foo=1&foo=2&foo=3` will result in the key `foo` having the value `1,2,3`.

One should note, though, with respect to the query string that the HTTP protocol does not place any particular strictures on query string syntax: everything in a URI following the `?` (and up to the first `#` indicating the beginning of the *fragment*, or the end of the URI, whichever comes first) is the *query*: its interpretation is completely up to the *authority* whose URI it is. Sadly, Microsoft's `HttpRequest` class makes the decision for you.

Comment: Someone edited my question to remove the asp-classic tag, the ASPTypeLibrary version of Request does not return NameValueCollections

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but maybe someone still need an answer to this and how to access different content from the `ScriptingContext`. It tooks me almost a year to find out how this works ...

This code works for me to get the `QueryString`. In the example I build it again to a complete string:

```
    foreach (var item in _scriptContext.Request.QueryString)
    {
      foreach (var q in _scriptContext.Request.QueryString[item])
        qs += item + "=" + q + "&";
    }
    if (qs.EndsWith("&")) qs = qs.Substring(0, qs.Length - 1);
```

In this context getting `ServerVariables`:

```
    var uri = "";
    foreach (var item in _scriptContext.Request.ServerVariables["URL"])
      uri = item.ToString();
```

`Application` and `Session` return the content *direct*:

```
    var app_var = _scriptContext.Application["application_var"]
    var sess_var = _scriptContext.Session["session_var"]
```

Reading a cookie works like this:

```
    dynamic value = (IReadCookie)_scriptContext.Request.Cookies["cookieName"];
    var yourCookie = value.Item().ToString();
```